# Swift How could I safely unwrap an optional property when filtering an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

I am trying to filter an array of objects with an optional property of the objects' class, so I was wondering what's the best way to unwrap this property safely without providing a default value. The property is of type Date so providing an alternative value feels like a hack, but I'm not sure how to do it better. I know how to safely unwrap a regular optional with guard but I'm not sure how to use this when filtering an array. The code I have is this:

```
let completedGoalsThisWeek = goals.filter { $0.returnWeek(date: $0.dateAchieved) == deviceWeek }.count
```

The property in question is dateAchieved and it will be nil in a lot of circumstances.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is it's a `Goal`'s job to determine what week a date is in? That's looks like a misplaced responsibility

Comment: Hm, I wanted to use these methods on arrays of Goal to filter them, so I thought I need to add them to the Goal class. How would you have done this differently?

Comment: A `Goal` happens to have a date, but that doesn't mean that date operations should be put into goal. Imagine there was another type, `PrereleaseSale` in your system. Would `returnWeek(date:)` go to `Goal`, or `PrereleaseSale`? Both have dates whose weeks need to be known, so it's equally applicable. The correct answer is neither, this function should probably as an extension on `Date`, or perhaps `Calendar`. I would also use a computed property instead of a function, calling it something like `weekNumber` (assuming I understand correctly, that it gives a number 0-51, or 1-52)

Comment: That makes sense, and it makes for much cleaner and logical syntax, so thank you for the tips. This does mean that I'll have to use your answer for filtering the array, even though I don't understand closures (tried a few times in the past, it still doesn't click).

Comment: You're using closures in your own question :) What doesn't click about closures?

Comment: I don't understand what they are used for or how they work, so how would you read a closure in plain English? I always read of the filter method as 'filter by *goals wildcard* where the method .returnWeek, taking in a parameter of date is equal to deviceWeek' Which part of that is the closer, the logic that gets execute inside the { }? What is the point of it? I'm relatively new to this, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197012/discussion-between-alexander-and-cristianmoisei).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error here

```
$0.returnWeek(date: $0.dateAchieved) == deviceWeek
```

can ve solved by making paramter `date` an optional which will make the return optional too but it will pass as you can compare an optional value with non-one

---

`returnWeek` Would be like

```
func returnWeek(date:Date?) -> TypeOFWeek? {
  guard let res = date else { return nil }
  // here return valid result 
}
```

OR

```
let completedGoalsThisWeek = goals.filter { $0.dateAchieved != nil ?  ( $0.returnWeek(date: $0.dateAchieved!) == deviceWeek ) : false }.count
```

---

Or better the model

```
class Model { 
  var toWeek: TypeOfWeek? {
    // do where what in function which uses dateAchieved
  }
}

let completedGoalsThisWeek = goals.filter { $0.toWeek  == deviceWeek }.count
```

Comment: Thanks @Sh_Khan for helping out again. Dumb question, but how do you make a parameter optional? What I mean is that if I add ? in the function it just asks me to unwrap it at a function level. So func returnWeek(date: Date?)

Comment: I disagree with this. You shouldn't add in optionality to appease call sites. Callers should handle their optionals first, and then call you with non-optional payloads, or not call you at all

Comment: @Alexander actually i didn't want to complicate the filter added another option

Comment: @CristianMoisei since the function exists in the model it's better to make a computed optional property instead of a function inside that model and make it like 3 snippt

Comment: @Sh_Khan It's much better than letting optionality creep into every facet of the app. What if I want to handle double optionals, too? Should the `returnWeek` function take double optionals? What about triple?

Comment: @Alexander btw added 3rd better option

Comment: @Sh_Khan I would suggest you remove the first 2 options entirely

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing special to it. Just unwrap the optional like you would in any other case:

```
let completedGoalsThisWeek = goals
    .lazy
    .filter { goal -> Bool in
        guard let dateAchieved = goal.dateAchieved else { return false }
        let isCurrentWeek = goal.returnWeek(date: dateAchieved) == deviceWeek
        return isCurrentWeek
    }.count
```

You *could* use `Optional.map` to shorten this, but I would advise against it, it's too cryptic:

```
let completedGoalsThisWeek = goals
    .lazy
    .filter { goal
        goal.dateAchieved.map { goal.returnWeek(date: $0) == deviceWeek } ?? false
    }.count
```

In either case, I suggest you use `.lazy.filter`, to prevent the intermediate allocation to hold an array of elements, if you're ultimately going to only count them and immediately discard them.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I've added more to my answer, I think it's worth keeping

Comment: Hey @Alexander, thanks for posting that answer, and I hope it helps others. But it's a little beyond my skills. Could you tell me a bit about what goal -> Bool in means?

Comment: @CristianMoisei It's just the typical syntax for closures, naming the first (and only) parameter as `goal` (replacing the implicit closure param `$0`), and defining the return type of the closure as being of type `Bool`. It's covered in the Swift Programming Language Guide. There's a whole section on closures, but I suggest you read the entire doc more generally. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html